# ORMLite does not know how to store class

Tags: android, sqlite, api, retrofit, ormlite

**Person.class**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName =PERSON_TABLE_NAME)
class Person{
    public final static String PERSON_TABLE_NAME="person";
        @DatabaseField
       private  String name;
        @DatabaseField
       private   String surname;
        @DatabaseField(id = true)
       private  int id;
        @ForeignCollectionField
       private ForeignCollection<Motivations> motivationsData;

    ArrayList<Motivations> motivations;

//getters and setters
    }
```

**My envelope Class to get Object from API**

```
    class PersonApiEnvelope{
         private String sign ;

    private int last_call;

    private List<Person> data;

    //getters and setters
        }
```

**Motivation.class**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName =MOTIVATIONS_TABLE_NAME)
    class Person{
        public final static String MOTIVATIONS_TABLE_NAME="motivations";
            @DatabaseField
           private  String name;
            @DatabaseField
          private   String content;
            @DatabaseField(id = true)
           private  int id;
            @DatabaseField (canBeNull = true,foreign= true)
           private Person person;

    //getters and setters
        }
```

I map response from Api into the PersonEnvelopeClass then i map data into the Person.class, then when I want to create `Dao<Person,Integer> personDAO = databaseHelper.getPersonDAO` ive got an error

> ORMLite does not know how to store class
>   com.example.k.Database.Model.Person for field person. Use another
>   class or a custom persister

Without ForeginCollection works fine.

How can I save ArrayList with many fields of other object without this error

I suppose I must rewrite the ArrayList to Collection because I cannot read collection from the api.

Dao personDAO = databaseHelper.getPersonDAO();  //here ive get an excepction

```
   List<Person> personList;         
         PersonApiEnvelope envelope = response.body();
                                personList = envelope.getData();

                                for(Person m: personList ){
      personDAO .assignEmptyForeignCollection(m,"motivationsData"); 
                                if(m.getMotivations()!=null){ 
           ForeignCollection<Motivations>  temp=m.getMotivationsData();
                                 temp.addAll(m.getMotivations());
                                 m.setMotivationsData(temp);
                                  }

personDAO.createOrUpdate(m);
}
```

I tried to use `@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)` instead of    `@ForeignCollectionField` but the data is not create in ormLite properly so i need to use `@ForeignCollectionField`

EDIT Ive changed Collection into ForeignCollection and assignEmptyForeignCollection but still got this error

Comment: Unfortunatly ormlite doesn't know how to store a List. Check out [ForeignCollection](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/ForeignCollection.html)

Comment: yup but it isnt list but ForeginCollection, thats why i rewrite it after get from the api and the ArrayList in Person class isnt a DatabaseField

Comment: But it's a ForeignCollectionField, which OrmLite tries to write in the DB and fails because it's a Collection and not a ForeignCollection. Personally I would not store the Motivations list at all, since you have the person field in Motivation so you can just query for all Motivations whose "person_id" matches the person.

Comment: Unfortunetlly I must do it this way. Your comment was helpfull Ive changed Collection into the ForeignCollection. Now I tried to asignassignEmptyForeignCollection to avoid NPE thanks for hints !

Comment: Ive changed for a ForeginColection and still have the same error

Comment: Have you looked at the docs?  See: http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collection